# Android Remove Application Widget - "Error loading widget"

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

I would like to remove the AppWidgets included in my application. The business has decided to not support our widget anymore. I have removed the receiver, the provider and all code associated with the widgets.

However when testing, I previous had one of my widgets on the home screen. When I update the app with the widget code removed, where the widget was previous on the home screen it now says:

"Problem loading widget"

Is there any way programmatically I can remove this widget or prevent this error message from displaying?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't remove widget from homescreen programmatically unless your app is launcher app . User has to remove it.

Comment: That is what I thought. We are just going to provide them with a message that we no longer support the widgets. Thanks.